# Using mobile tools module in Drupal6 with varnish?

Tags: drupal-6, varnish, pressflow

Can we use Mobile Tools module in Drupal6 with Varnish?
I doubt varnish will cache the index page and will not allow redirection to mobile version of the page.

Any work arround?

Comment: I would suggest to try it out and use the Varnish statistics tools to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your server return different responses based on the used device/browser. This means your pages 'vary' based on the used User-Agent http request header, and in theory you should instruct any http proxy/cache in between to only use a cached version if the User-Agent string is the same by adding a http response header:

```
Vary: User-Agent
```

However, because browsers like Internet Explorer (unlike Chrome) use many slightly different User-Agent headers, this will completely kill your cache hit ratio. You need a smarter cache to understand that `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)` for your purposes is equal to `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.0; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.1; SV1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)`, or any other user-agent string used by a desktop browser.

There are two options for you to solve this with Varnish:

1: Do mobile user-agent detection yourself in varnish logic, the same way mobile tools does it. E.g.:

```
vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.user-agent ~ 'ipad|ipod|iphone|android|mini opera|blackberry|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|kindle|mobile|pda|psp|treo') {
    hash += "mobile"
  }
}
```

2: Or, always set a session cookie `mobile=true` or `mobile=false` after you've seen the first request, and only serve cached pages for requests with this cookie.

And after googling a bit, you should read: http://fangel.github.com/mobile-detection-varnish-drupal/